# Laravel in public 'www' directory how to protect

Tags: php, laravel

How to protect laravel app if I upload it to the public folder -'www' on my hosting ,I can't upload the app to the parent of 'www' folder because I previosly uploaded Laravel app folder to the parent directory of 'www', everything worked fine, exept mkdir() function doesn't work when laravel app is in the parent folder of 'www', so how can I protect Laravel app when its in the public folder?

Comment: `.htaccess` and put `Deny from All` in your Lavarel root

Comment: If you can, set the root folder of your hosting to www/public. If you can't you'll have to configure a redirection (with the .htaccess if you're using Apache)

Comment: thanks , I'll try both methods

Comment: should I do '.htaccess Deny from All' in each folder - app, bootstrap and vendor?

Comment: I think you should instead be thinking about how to fix your `mydir` permissions in the parent folder. Putting Laravel in your public directory goes against every best practice you can think of. Laravel isn't even designed to work correctly in that scenario; it specifically designed to be in the parent folder, and with only its `public` folder accessible as the web root. Don't compromise your whole site just because you can't get your linux permissions worked out. (in fact, that probably makes it even more important that you don't do it!)

Comment: I use hostgator shared plan, I have contacted support many times, I can't fix permissions unfortunatley (, what hosting do you use for laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Put your Laravel application in 'www' folder and create the `.htaccess` file in the root of your app. Make sure you have your `mod_rewrite` module on.

```
#.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

This will remove `.../public/...` from URL.